# How to Sort and join according to Number/Counter inside the file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, sort, join

I want to join two files according to number in the file, two number same file

```
Toyota   model1 
BMW      model2
Benz     model3
BMW      model4 
BMW      model5
Benz     model6 
Benz     model7
```

and second file

```
class C    model1
class E    model2
class A    model3
class W    model4
class W    model5
class C    model6
class A    model7
```

I want to join the two file according to the number, like this, joining each model number with each other in one file.

```
Toyota      class C  model1
BMW         class E  model2
Benz        class A  model3
BMW         class W  model4 
BMW         class W  model5  
Benz        Class C  model6
Benz        Class A  model7
```

after that delete the 'model' string

My code,

```
sort -V file1 > new_file1 
sort -V file2 > new_file2 
join newfile1 new_file2 > result.txt
sed 's/model[(1-9)]//g' result.txt > result_1.txt
```

the problem I'm getting an Error while joining the files

```
join: file1.txt:10: is not sorted: 03Benz   model   249
join: file2.txt:4: is not sorted: BMW   model   2
```

what if I want to count frequency after that

```
   ( this pair happen in the text 2 times) after joined 
Toyota      class C  1
BMW         class E  1
Benz        class A  2
BMW         class W  2
Benz        Class C  1
```

Comment: Thanks, two times I'm try to count how many  pairs came together (car model and class)  in my file

Comment: Sorry for that, I re-wrote it in more clear way

Comment: Are the columns in first and second file separated by spaces or by tabulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join`.

It looks like changing the first space character in the file to something other than space will be sufficient to convert the file whitespace-delimited records.

Here's an implementation that replaces the first space with `%` and then joins on the second column of each file.

```
$ cat file2 | sed -e 's/ /%/' | join -1 2 -2 2 - file1
```

or

```
$ <file2 sed -e 's/ /%/' | join -1 2 -2 2 - file1
```

which produces

```
model1 class%C Toyota
model2 class%E BMW
model3 class%A Benz
model4 class%W BMW
model5 class%W BMW
model6 class%C Benz
model7 class%A Benz
```

If you need to convert it to a tab-delimited format, you can use `tr`.

```
tr ' %' '\t '
```

Answer (score 0):

Join is the correct tool and you don't need any other conversion other than sorted files.

```
join -12 -23 -o 1.1 2.1 2.2 0 file1 file2 |column -t
Toyota  class  C  model1
BMW     class  E  model2
Benz    class  A  model3
BMW     class  W  model4
BMW     class  W  model5
Benz    class  C  model6
Benz    class  A  model7
```

Join is by default handling fields with space separation.
Option -12 means first file second field
Option -23 means second file third field
Option -o means format output:
  1.1 = file1 field 1
  2.1 = file2 field 1
  0   = common /joined field

Apply LC_ALL=C in front of sort and join commands to ensure correct sorting and correct joining (i.e LC_ALL=C sort file)

About the counting part you can do something like this:

```
join -12 -23 -o 1.1 2.1 2.2 0 file1 file2 |cut -d' ' -f1-3 |sort |uniq -c
      1 BMW class E
      2 BMW class W
      2 Benz class A
      1 Benz class C
      1 Toyota class C
```

[You can see both tests above online here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNmFxNEdabkxUcHc)

Comment: @Lona Answer updated with counting part and online testing